# React-typescript: Type 'IPayloadData' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: react-typescript

I am using React-typescript for my app. My target is to fetch the data and display to my own custom Checkbox. I can able to map the data but I am getting from my valuse. I am sure its a Typescript error. This is the error I am getting: `Type 'IPayloadData' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2322`.

**This is my type interface**

```
export interface IPayloadData {
  label?: string;
  value?: string;
}

export interface IData {
  uuid?: string;
  name?: string;
  description?: string;
  tasks?: IPayloadData[];
}
```

**This is my data which I am pulling from my redux's store**

```
   const tasks = useSelector((state: IRootState) => state.properties.details);
    const allTasks = tasks?.[propertyUUID]?.data?.tasks?.data;
```

**This is my custom checkbox where I want to display my data**

```
<CheckBoxGroup
            id="issueListPropertiesPicker"
            name="issueListPropertiesPicker"
            choices={allTasks?.map((i: any) => ({
              "label": i.name,
              "value": i.uuid
            }))}
            values={values?.tasks || []} // IN HERE I am getting typescript error
            onChange={(e) => handleChange({ "tasks": e })}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown selection, which is controlled in `values` property, is being set with a array of `IPayloadData`, instead of an array of strings, when `tasks` is not null.

I suppose you are trying to pass the list of `uuid`s from `tasks`, when any, like this:

> The line with the change has the comment: // **HERE IS THE CHANGE

```
<CheckBoxGroup
   id="issueListPropertiesPicker"
   name="issueListPropertiesPicker"
   choices={allTasks?.map((i: any) => ({
      "label": i.name,
      "value": i.uuid
   }))}
   values={tasks?.map((dta: IData) => dta.uuid)  || []} // **HERE IS THE CHANGE
   onChange={(e) => handleChange({ "tasks": e })}
/>
```

Comment: I am trying get  IPayloadData's value. But with your logic I tried to like this: `values={values?.tasks.map((dta: IPayloadData) => dta.value) || []}`. But now i am getting different error: `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`

Comment: That is because `tasks` is defined at the same level of `allTasks`, but I didn't realized it when I copied your sample. My bad.